# Strange results from CNN in Keras

Tags: python, classification, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I have a binary classification problem. I designed a model with convolution kernels in first layers and then dense layers. As the output layer, however, I used a **softmax** layer with size 2, and then used **one-hot encoding** on my labels.
It means my labels look like a 2-bit number: either `01` or `10`.

Also, I report the following metrics: *fp*, *fn*, *tp*, *tn*, *recall*, *precision* and *accuracy*.

My problem is: I get really strange results during training as seen below. *Accuracy*, *precision* and *recall* are always equal. To be more specific: `fp=fn`, `tp=tn`, `recall=precision=accuracy`!!

Can somebody explain that? and how to fix it?

Here is my code to preprocess the data, build the model and fit.

```
def preprocess_data(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)

    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

    # normalization
    max_signal_value = max(X_train.max(), X_test.max())
    X_train = X_train/max_signal_value 
    X_test = X_test/max_signal_value 

    # make binary
    y_train = np.array(list(map(lambda x:int(x==1), y_train)))
    y_test = np.array(list(map(lambda x:int(x==1), y_test)))

    # One-hot encoding label
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

metrics = [
    keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name="fn"),
    keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name="fp"),
    keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name="tn"),
    keras.metrics.TruePositives(name="tp"),
    keras.metrics.Precision(name="precision"),
    keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall"),
    'accuracy'
]

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = (5,5), padding = 'same',
                   activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))


    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=opt, metrics=metrics)

    return model

LeNet_model = build_model()
LeNet_model.summary()

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = preprocess_data(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

history = LeNet_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=1,
                        steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0], validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        validation_steps=X_test.shape[0], verbose=1)
```

The result looks like:

````
74008/74008 [=======] - loss: 0.5173 - fn: 16423.0000 - fp: 16423.0000 - tn: 57585.0000 - tp: 57585.0000 - precision: 0.7781 - recall: 0.7781 - accuracy: 0.7781 - cat_accuracy: 0.7781 - val_loss: 0.5173 - val_fn: 4643.0000 - val_fp: 4643.0000 - val_tn: 15487.0000 - val_tp: 15487.0000 - val_precision: 0.7693 - val_recall: 0.7693 - val_accuracy: 0.7693 - val_cat_accuracy: 0.7693
Epoch 2/50

74008/74008 [=======] - loss: 0.4986 - fn: 16404.0000 - fp: 16404.0000 - tn: 57604.0000 - tp: 57604.0000 - precision: 0.7783 - recall: 0.7783 - accuracy: 0.7783 - cat_accuracy: 0.7783 - val_loss: 0.5200 - val_fn: 4644.0000 - val_fp: 4644.0000 - val_tn: 15486.0000 - val_tp: 15486.0000 - val_precision: 0.7693 - val_recall: 0.7693 - val_accuracy: 0.7693 - val_cat_accuracy: 0.7693```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's a `binary classification`, you should change the last layers to `1 unit` with `sigmoid activation`. The loss function also should change to `binary_crossentropy` instead.

Also, for the y, just keep its value as `0` or `1`, no need to do the `One-Hot Encoding` to make it become `01` or `10`. It's redundant and not recommended.

You can try this code for the model building:

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = (5,5), padding = 'same',
                   activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))


    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=metrics)

return model
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually, I've already done that. The results were not good. Therefore, I thought maybe categorical approach would work better. The question here is, why doesn't this code work? It seems logical to me: softmax with 2 output should work just like sigmoid with 1 output. Or do I miss something?